# Properties of Integrals strict inequalities greater then 0

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a function $f$ such that $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$ then by properties of integrals I know that $\int f(x)dx \geq 0$. suppose that  $\int f(x)dx=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$. How can I show that $\frac{22}{7} > \pi$?

Answer (score 1):

If you know $\frac{22}{7}-\pi\geq0$ and you know $\pi$ is irrational,
then you also know $\frac{22}{7}-\pi\neq0$, from which the desired
result follows (this is not related to integrals).

Answer (score 0):

The assumptions $f(x)\ge 0$ and  $$\int f(x)dx=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$ does not imply$$ \frac{22}{7} > \pi$$ unless you have the condition $f(x)>0$ on some interval of the domain.

Make sure to check the assumpsions again.